# English equivalent of the expression “a longer arm than résumé”

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

I've heard a non-native English speaker use the expression "in this place, having a long arm to scratch someone else's back is more important than having a long résumé", conveying the idea of favoritism in a place influencing the promotion of people within. I would like to know if there is an equivalent in English to such expression.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The phrase

> It's not what you know but who you know.

seems to have similar connotations, although is more about knowing the right people, than currying favour with them.

There is the more salacious

> Sleep your way to the top

which takes the back scratching a little more literally.

Answer (score 4):

I understood your question as asking for an idiom for nepotism or sycophantic promotion.

One could say, "When it comes to promotions in this company, *flattery will get you everywhere*."

There's a [theory on the origin of "*Bob's your uncle*"](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-bob1.htm) which is based on nepotism (although the saying doesn't mean that anymore).

Answer (score 1):

At first I misinterpreted the quotation, thinking it to mean, "*it's more important to help other people than to look after yourself*;" that is, employees should be looking out for others – particularly others within the company.  In the U.S., many quotes promoting such an unselfish attitude are borrowed from the world of sports, such as:

> *Everyone is needed, but no one is necessary*. (Bruce Coslet, American football coach)

but the most famous I thought of was:

> There is no "I" in team.

Getting back to your question, some have parodied that expression, to put it more in line with the underhanded dealings of a workplace such as you describe:

> "There is no "I" in team – but there is an "M" and an "E"!

implying that, at the end of the day, you've got to "look out for #1."

---

It's not a full maxim, and I think it may be an Americanism, but the verb phrase [*buck for*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/buck-for) can be used:

> *You know that and I know that, 
>                            but somebody's bucking for a 
>                            promotion*. (from the movie *Fletch*)

---

All that said, I don't think any of these are as apt as Matt's "*it's not what you know, but who you know*" suggestion.

Comment: I think the one you point out as closest is furthest away. The question is about favouritism, where as your quote promotes altruism.

Comment: Plus the phrase means "It's more important to do people favours, than it is to be smart and experienced", and the implication is that you are doing the *right* people favours, rather than help in a team-oriented fashion.

Comment: @MattЭллен: I'll freely admit, I was a little confused by the word "favoritism" embedded in the O.P.'s question.  Now that you've cleared it up, it appears like I've entirely missed the point!  Now I'm put in the awkward position where I should upvote your answer, and perhaps downvote my own!  (I'll have to decide whether I should downvote, delete, or try to salvage my answer)

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is a phrase I can't think of, to match the OP's curiosity, so don't give up!

Comment: @MattЭллен: Thanks for the encouragement, and the correction!  I've done my best to salvage my mess...

Comment: Or ***whom** you know*. :)

Comment: To the phrase `There is no "I" in team` I prefer the ripost : `but there's a "U" in C**T`

Comment: @SamHolder and you are still employed?

Comment: @tchrist, I'm wondering, why would it be **whom**? "It is not what you know but it is who you know that counts." is shortened to: "It's not what you know but who you know." Right?

Comment: @JLG Er no.  It has to be whom because the relative pronoun’s role in the subordinate clause is that of that clause’s object, not its subject. Because it’s not “You know he” but “You know him”, it must also be “You know whom”, and so with inversion, “whom you know”. See how that works now?

Comment: @tchrist, So everyone who says "it's who you know" is wrong?

Comment: @JLG I don’t know what you mean by “wrong”. Many native speakers never use *whom* at all, or only ever use it as the object of preposition, or suppress it when it occurs in word-initial position in a sentence. For them, it is not “wrong”, because they do not recognize the “rule”. But if you are someone who follows the rule that says to use *who* for subjects and *whom* for objects, no matter where they should fall, then yes, it is “wrong” in that it breaks that simple rule. How then to judge “right” and “wrong” here? It’s a common enough practice, certainly, but in formal writing? Dubious.